# Is it possible to replicate this image effect in CSS?

Tags: css

Wondering if CSS is far enough along that it is possible to apply this complicated effect to text:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend svg instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty example. You can play around with the number of steps and the opacity.

```css
body { 
  background: #222;
}
h1#css3D-text-shadow {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: rgb(249,224,70);
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial Black, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  text-shadow: 
    0 .1em 0 rgba(249,224,70,0.8),
    0 .2em 0 rgba(213,202,62,0.8),
    0 .3em 0 rgba(177,180,54,0.8),
    0 .4em 0 rgba(141,158,46,0.8),
    0 .5em 0 rgba(122,148,42,0.8),
    0 .6em 0 rgba(104,137,38,0.8),
    0 .7em 0 rgba(86,126,34,0.8),
    0 .8em 0 rgba(68,115,30,0.8),
    0 .9em 0 rgba(50,104,26,0.8),
    0 1em 0 rgba(32,93,22,0.8);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #f7d60d;
}
```

```html
<h1 id=css3D-text-shadow>MICROSOFT</h1>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

p {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0px #ffff0052, 0 5px 0px #ffff0052, 0 8px 0px #ffff0052, 0 11px 0px #ffff0052, 0 14px 0px #ffff0052, 0 16px 0px #ffff0052, 0 19px 0px #ffff0052, 0 21px 0px #ffff0052, 0 24px 0px #ffff0052, 0 27px 0px #ffff0052, 0 29px 0px #ffff0052, 0 32px 0px #ffff0052;
}
```

```html
<p>MICROSOFT</p>
```